# Plotting categorical variable against numeric variable in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My DataFrame's structure

```
trx.columns
Index(['dest', 'orig', 'timestamp', 'transcode', 'amount'], dtype='object')
```

I'm trying to plot `transcode` (transaction code) against `amount` to see the how much money is spent per transaction. I made sure to convert `transcode` to a categorical type as seen below.

```
trx['transcode']
...
Name: transcode, Length: 21893, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [1, 17, 99]
```

The result I get from doing `plt.scatter(trx['transcode'], trx['amount'])` is

[Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PKW7.png)

While the above plot is not entirely wrong, I would like the X axis to contain just the three possible values of `transcode` [1, 17, 99] instead of the entire [1, 100] range.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at a box plot, violin plot, or bar plot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In matplotlib 2.1 you can plot categorical variables by using strings. I.e. if you provide the column for the x values as string, it will recognize them as categories.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : np.random.choice([1,17,99], size=100),
                   "y" : np.random.rand(100)*100})

plt.scatter(df["x"].astype(str), df["y"])
plt.margins(x=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In order to optain the same in matplotlib <=2.0 one would plot against some index instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : np.random.choice([1,17,99], size=100),
                   "y" : np.random.rand(100)*100})

u, inv = np.unique(df["x"], return_inverse=True) 
plt.scatter(inv, df["y"])
plt.xticks(range(len(u)),u)
plt.margins(x=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The same plot can be obtained using seaborn's [`stripplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html#seaborn.stripplot):

```
sns.stripplot(x="x", y="y", data=df)
```

And a potentially nicer representation can be done via seaborn's [`swarmplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html#seaborn.swarmplot):

```
sns.swarmplot(x="x", y="y", data=df)
```

[image]