# Read two columns and draw the graph

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I already asked my problem: [How to read two columns using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687701/how-to-read-two-columns-using-python), but my goal is to draw a graph `oX = f(oY)`.

I tried with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style    
import csv

with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        res = row[0].split()
        oX = res[0]
        oY = res[1]
        print (oX , oY)
```

It does not work for me.

Comment: What does it mean that it does not work? That description does not help us.

Comment: Hi eyllanesc,  I wanted to convert oX and oY into a list, to draw a graph

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269695/plotting-categorical-variable-against-numeric-variable-in-matplotlib) for how to plot categorical variables as scatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting labels (strings) using `scatter` is only possible if you are using matplotlib 2.1.0 or higher. 2.1.0 is the latest stable release at the time of writing this answer.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import csv
x = []
y = []
with open('e:/projects/data.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        res = row[0].split()
        oX = res[0]
        oY = res[1]
        x.append(oX)
        y.append(oY)
        print (oX, oY)
```

Using your original code only the last coordinate in your input file is plotted. You need to store `oX` and `oY` in a list, for example in `x` and `y`.

```
plt.scatter (x, y, linewidth = 0.1, color = "black", label = 'V')
plt.show ()
```

Using the input from your other questions, your graph should look like this

[image]

Comment: Hi Jaco, Thank you,  I will install anaconda3, will it work?

Comment: your output (picture), is exactly what I want to do

Comment: I had to use `pip install matplotlib`. Conda was still installing 3.0.0. That might, however, be due to the order of my conda channels.

Comment: Thank you **JACO**